# Landing page dropdown items display horizontally

Tags: html, css

My code displays the dropdown items horizontally on the nav bar. I would like them to be displayed as a dropdown list on the parent item ("Account"). The nested listed I created doesn't seem to be working. Any help would be appreciated!

I'm trying to do this purely in HTML/CSS.

```
<header>
<nav class="menu">
  <ol>
    <li><img src="images/Machoire logo.png"></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Members</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Notifications</a></li>   

    <li><a href="#">Account</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ol>
</nav>
</header>


header img {
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.menu {
    background-color: white;
    top: 450px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 40px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}


ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

header * {
    display: inline;
}

header li {
    margin: 20px;
}

header a {
    color: grey;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header a:hover {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: What's the CSS you have tried?

Comment: Just added the CSS now!

Comment: Please see my answer. Does this work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Below is a working snippet with what I think you're trying to accomplish. You need to absolutely position your dropdown element below the trigger and use a hover property on the trigger to activate it (in this case, changing the `display` from `none` to `block`).

```css
header img {
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.menu {
    background-color: white;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
.dropdown-trigger {
  position:relative;
}
.dropdown {
  position:absolute;
  top:15px;
  right:-15px;
  display:none;
}
.dropdown > li {
  display:block;
}
header li {
    margin: 15px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.dropdown-trigger:hover > ul {
  display:block;
}
header a {
    color: grey;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
header a:hover {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<header>
<nav class="menu">
  <ol>
    <li><img src="images/Machoire logo.png"></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Members</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Notifications</a></li>   

    <li class="dropdown-trigger"><a href="#">Account</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ol>
</nav>
</header>
```